# Microsoft Flow mapping values dynamically

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps, power-automate

We are connecting one our applications to Microsoft Flow. To achieve one of our functions we need to have Microsoft Flow serve outputs to dynamic data.

Let me explain what I meant,

```
{
    'Firstname': 'John',
    'Lastname': 'Doe'
}
```

if this is the input our API needs it's easy to form this input using flow because with the UI it's easy to map values from former output to Firstname and Lastname fields. But,

```
{
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3'
}
```

This is the input we need for our api. Mapping dynamic data. Meaning that the value mapping UI should be dynamic. The `keys` should be taken from our API.

This is a stripped down version of our actual problem. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to be able to use a dynamic schema:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/integrating-custom-api/

This will allow you to define the schema of the inputs (or even outputs). For example, Flow will call your endpoint to get the dynamic schema, which will then return the keys, and Flow will use that for its inputs.